# How to use multiple configuration files using Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to use different configuration file for my development and production server. I want to define different database configuration for each server and different logging procedure.

So when I run on my server I just change the `index.php` file.

Development:

```
// developement
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/development.php';
// production
// $config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/production.php';
```

Production:

```
// developement
// $config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/development.php';
// production
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/production.php';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this article give some information to you.

[Yii Framework Separate Configurations for Different Environments](http://www.hollowdevelopers.com/2011/05/14/yii-framework-separate-configurations-for-different-environments/)

Answer (score 3):

My solution is also based on [Yii Framework Separate Configurations for Different Environments](http://www.hollowdevelopers.com/2011/05/14/yii-framework-separate-configurations-for-different-environments/). Advantage of this method in fact that common configuration are stored in *config/main.php* and only differences are stored in *config/main_prod.php* and *config/main_dev.php* thanks to [CMap::mergeArray](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMap#mergeArray-detail).

*config/main.php* example:

```
<?php

$config = array( ... );

switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
    case 'your-prod-server-name.com':
        $config = CMap::mergeArray(
            $config,
            require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/main_prod.php')
        );
        break;
    default:
        $config = CMap::mergeArray(
            $config,
            require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/main_dev.php')
        );
        break;
}

return $config;
```

Of course, instead of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` you can use `YII_DEBUG`:

```
<?php

$config = array( ... );

if (YII_DEBUG) {
    $config = CMap::mergeArray(
        $config,
        require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/main_dev.php')
    );
} else {
    $config = CMap::mergeArray(
        $config,
        require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/main_prod.php')
    );
}

return $config;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'yourdomain.com') {
    $config = dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/production.php';
} else {
    defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
    defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 3);
    $config = dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/development.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if only change database connection
    `'db'=>require($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='127.0.0.1' ? 'db_dev.php' : 'db.php'),`

and create files in config dir with content
    `<?php return array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'schemaCachingDuration' => 3600,
    'enableProfiling'=>true,
    'enableParamLogging' => true,
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
    ); ?>`