# git ignore Yii database details

Tags: yii, configuration

Some of the details in the `main.php` needed by all application instances (URL details) and some details will be specific to each application instance (database details).

Is there any idea to separate the database details from `protected/config/main.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include the shared configuration from another PHP file:

*main.php:*

```
return array
(
   ....
   'components' => array
   (
      'db' => include('sharedDatabaseConfiguration.php');
   )
);
```

*sharedDatabaseConfiguration.php:*

```
return array('host' => ...);
```

You might have to add a path or something, depending where the file is stored.

Edit: Btw, Yii also has a fancy CMap::mergeArray() function that can do something similar (in case you want to "augment" the contents of a single config file with that from another one. Look at the default generated console.php for an example of that.

Answer (score 2):

You can find an idea here: [Manage application configuration in different modes](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/32/manage-application-configuration-in-different-modes/) .
Basically it works by importing a different PHP file (your db configuration) and merging the included`array`s:

```
<?php
return CMap::mergeArray(
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/db-config.php'), 
    array(
          'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
          'name' => 'Page Title',
          ...
    )
);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use separate configuration file (e.g. protected/config/production.php), that is based on your main configuration file and that overrides some settings using `CMap::mergeArray` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13321476/3206908) suggests:

```
return CMap::mergeArray(
    require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/main.php'),
    array(
        'components' => array(
            'db' => array(
                'connectionString' => '...',
                'username' => '...',
                'password' => '...',
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Then you can add protected/config/production.php to .gitignore.